# Run code only once after an application is opened android webview

Tags: android, webview

I want to run code only once after an application is opened. I try onpagefinished but when I refresh page the code run again. Sorry for my bad English. This is my code.

```
@Override
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);

                my code
}
```